# How to iterate a for-each inside a for-each, where the outer for-each is a variable

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010649/how-to-use-for-each-inside-another-for-each-in-xsl) which I thought would be the answer to my issue.

This is just test code at the moment. I have a dummy XML data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NamesToHighlight Version="180900" xmlns="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
    <Name>Mr Happy</Name>
    <Name>Mr Grumpy</Name>
</NamesToHighlight>
```

This file gets linked into my XSL and I am just doing testing at this stage. Now, this code works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

  <xsl:variable name="Names" select="document('NamesToHighlight.XML')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140.css"/>
        <title>Title of Schedule</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
          <div class="containerPage">
            <p>
              <xsl:value-of select="WeeklyBibleReading"/>
            </p>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It correctly shows 4 Bible Reading references:

[image: Test 1]

But if I try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

  <xsl:variable name="Names" select="document('NamesToHighlight.XML')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140.css"/>
        <title>Title of Schedule</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Names/msa:NamesToHighlight/msa:Name">
          <xsl:variable name="NameToHighlight" select="."/>
          <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="$NameToHighlight"/>
          </p>
            <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
              <div class="containerPage">
                <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="WeeklyBibleReading"/>
              </p>
              </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It now only shows the names:

[image: Test 2]

I thought it was related to the linked question, so I tried:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
```

But it made no difference. I even tried prefixing with `//` and that made no difference. I am assuming that the "context" is the "variable" I am iterating. How do I handle this?

I am not sure I can actually do what I want. It seems that I might have to change my application logic and make the list of names actually part of the "MeetingWorkBook" XML file. But i will wait to see if anyone has any advice on this.

---

At the moment I have resolved this byc hanging my logic. If I move the list of names from the external XML into the schedule, then I can use two `for-each` loops with **root** paths. All good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try by placing the current XML in a variable, such as:

```
<xsl:variable name="curr_document" select="."/>
```

and referencing that later in the 2nd for-each loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="$curr_document/MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
```

Your XSLT should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:msa="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Names" select="document('NamesToHighlight.XML')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="curr_document" select="."/>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140.css"/>
                <title>Title of Schedule</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="$Names/msa:NamesToHighlight/msa:Name">
                    <xsl:variable name="NameToHighlight" select="."/>
                    <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$NameToHighlight"/>
                    </p>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$curr_document/MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
                        <div class="containerPage">
                            <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select="WeeklyBibleReading"/>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```